# CATransition slow and picture jump when do transition on a large size picture

Tags: iphone

I used CATransition to do transition between two images. But I found that if the image file size is large, the transition will be slow or jump.

Especially on case:

```
type:kCATransitionMoveIn, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, 
subtypes:kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
```

Is there anyone met the same problem?

any comments?